# Simple Return to Top Button Does Not Work with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, location-href

I am writing a web app using AngularJS on the frontend and I'm implementing a return to top button at the bottom of the page.

```
   <h1 id = "top">
    ..........
   <a href="#top">Return to Top</a>
```

However, this does not work at all. I'm lost because this has worked before on other apps that do not use Angular. So do I have to do something different here?

Comment: Is your app using iframes?

Comment: No it isn't. Just AngularJS

Comment: Does your app have those spaces between `id` and the `=`?

Comment: Yes it does and I tried taking out the spaces as well. Does not work

Comment: Can you try to add `target="_self"` to the anchor tag. I think Angular $location service is intercepting your navigation.

Comment: @Chandermani wow target="_self" solved the problem!! Thank you so much. Why would $location service intercept my navigation though?

Comment: Read the developer guide on [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location). The location service intercept all redirection unless you override it. See section `Html link rewriting`, But anyways you robbed me of my credit by posting this as an answer :)

Comment: New bug, so if I try to do another return to top button in a second page, it doesn't work for that page and just redirects to the first page. Like it doesn't go back to the top of the second page. Note that I used a different id for the top button; on the second page, I have id="top_second_page".....<a href="#top_second_page">, also I added target = "_self" and even tried the other targets. @Chandermani any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add    target="_self"   to href will solve the problem. Thanks to @Chandermani

Answer (score 1):

There's no inherent reason that Angular should interfere with the native operation of a link. Is it possible that the link isn't doing what you expect because the h1 element with the anchor isn't in the DOM anymore at the time you click the link? For example, could you have conditionally removed a parent or ancestor element of that h1 tag with an ng-if directive?

Update: Apparently there is an inherent reason that Angular would interfere. Thanks for the lesson, @Chandermani.

Comment: It's not just the h1, I have tried it with a few other tags as well even the body tag. Nothing works. Could Angular staterouter be doing something?